How to add Many cells in google Sheet
You have a list of expenses in cells B2 through B10 on your Google Sheet. How would you calculate the total amount of all these expenses using a formula?

=sum(B2:B10) `

=SUM(B2:B10)
This formula adds up all the values in the range from B2 to B10 and gives you the total sum of your expenses.
